# Как скомпилировать расширение sphinxsearch под HHVM?

Tags: php, sphinx

http://sphinxsearch.com/

Как скомпилировать расширение sphinxsearch client под HHVM?
При попытке воспользоваться расширением, ранее используемым на php-fpm, выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught exception: Could not open extension
>   /usr/lib/php5/20121212/sphinx.so: /usr/lib/php5/20121212/sphinx.so:
>   undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string

По информации источника
http://hhvm.h4cc.de/package/lostcause/sphinxsearch состояние библиотеки Not tested

Нашел мануал Converting a PHP Extension to HHVM (не заморочился)
http://www.sklar.com/software/php/2015/05/07/converting-a-php-extension-to-hhvm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве решения проблемы воспользовался библиотекой Sphinx Search PHP Client. Устанавливается через Composer, класс SphinxClient доступен в пространстве имен Sphinx. Протестировано, работает.

https://github.com/gigablah/sphinxphp